# Сидеть(,) не двигаясь

Tags: деепричастия

Ставятся ли запятые в этом выражении?

"Гоша заметил, что сидит(,) не двигаясь(,) уже довольно долго, поэтому решил размять мышцы."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужна. Как минимум - совсем не обязательна.

Это обстоятельство образа действия, выраженное одиночным деепричастием, по функции сближается с наречием. В таких случаях обособление не требуется.

Есть, правда, одна тонкость. В подобных вопросах (квалификация как образа действия) нет абсолютных правил, последнее слово в конечном счете всегда остается за автором. Но тут уж очень большим оригиналом надо быть, чтобы не признать за этим деепричастием обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Здравствуйте!) Согласна с вами на все 100, простите, что опубликовала свой ответ, не видя вашего. Пишем одно и то же). Всего доброго!

Comment: @Екатерина да что вы в самом деле! Зачем извиняться-то? Да и за что?! Рад видеть, кстати.

Answer (score 2):

В предложенном для анализа случае запятые лучше не ставить.

Если деепричастие употреблено без зависимых слов и после глагола-сказуемого, то оно превращается в наречие (процесс адвербиализации); запятые чаще всего не ставятся.

***Гоша заметил, что сидит не двигаясь (= неподвижно) уже довольно долго, поэтому решил размять мышцы.***

[Переход деепричастий в наречия](https://info.wikireading.ru/276610)